# A way to stop MpsSvc (Windows Firewall) service in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-firewall, windows-services

Is there actually a way to **stop** MpsSvc.exe service in Windows 10 without a reboot?

I can stop the service neither via [UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQxKR.png) nor via [cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTFtP.png).

For now, I only know a method when you set the startup type to "disabled" and restart the machine.

The purpose of this operation is to temporary enable firewall service, add firewall rules, and restore the initial service state, if it was initially disabled. This happens during installation. The alternative to this solution is to add rules directly to the registry, but I would like to avoid it as it's [not recommended](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2007.06.vistafirewall.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: @Biswapriyo, updated the details.

Comment: Just disable it quickly via admin elevated command prompt if needed instead via `netsh advfirewall set allprofiles state off` to re-enable simply run `netsh advfirewall set allprofiles state on`

Comment: @Biswapriyo, you can't add rules via cmd/powershell if the service is stopped.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT, initially the service is **stopped**, I can **start** it, but can't stop it back.

Comment: Thank you, @PimpJuiceIT, for your involvement. But I see some problems with the suggested solution: 
1) I need to apply only several rules, not the whole policy. Though I admit that policy export is a more civilized method;
2) to import the policy you still need a running FW service.

Let me explain the situation better. Initially, a user has a **stopped** FW service (not disabled), the installer **starts** the service, applies rules and **tries to restore the initial state** (which is "stopped").

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78590/discussion-between-corio-and-pimp-juice-it).